# What is a good way to prioritize threads waiting on the same blocking operation in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, algorithm, c++11, thread-priority

There is a single blocking queue. There is a pool of identical workers, that simply wait on conditional variable when something is pushed to queue, and try to pop from queue. Let's say that queue contains tasks.

In an ideal situation the threads will pop tasks uniformly. I want to add some bias to that probability, so that each worker will pop the certain percent of total amount of tasks - according to it's priority. But no thread should be idle intentionally, if there are unprocessed tasks in the queue.

#### Trivial example.

There are 3 workers, and 111 tasks, one task per second goes to queue. Each task takes about 1 second to be processed. The priorities of workers are 10, 1, 100. Then the workers should pop *about* 10, 1 and 100 tasks each.

---

Is there a convenient way to implement such mechanism using standard conditional variables and mutexes? - The probabilistic approach is fine.

Comment: Instead of adding thread priority, Just give each thread its own queue and make the task dealer deal the tasks according to your priority rule ?

Comment: @Malkocoglu Then I have to implement the task-stealing mechanism to prevent starvation of individual threads. That's what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: You can add a "proxy" which is the only notified of new tasks; then it can assign the job according to worker priority

Comment: @Sga: but how would this proxy know who is available ? In essence, it seems that you are advising to re-implement a condition variable with the priority aspect built-in.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: it doesn't matter if worker is available or not, proxy just has to divide tasks in queues of different lengths. Goal is that *each worker will pop the certain percent of total amount of tasks*, regardless of worker speed or task length. Workers must "register" to the proxy with their priority, and they'll receive the right *quantity* of tasks

Comment: @Sga that's my bad - I have to reformulate the question. But the Matthieu M. got the idea: threads shouldn't wait if they are idle, but if there are more than one pending thread for a single task, the priority should take effect.

Comment: @abyss.7 that makes sense :-) what about exposing some thread state like running/idle?

Comment: @abyss.7 My comment was based on your example and threads should not have to steal task if each got their own queue, the task dealer was responsible for the task distribution. If you want that threads should not wait if they are idle, it is hard (maybe impossible) to distribute the tasks as 100/10/1.

Answer (score 2):

Create a `priority_queue` of waiting threads. When a new task is added to the task queue, pop the min thread from the `priority_queue` to handle the new task.

Comment: So, in short: create a condition variable but replace the list of waiting threads by a priority list of waiting threads :)